# Subtract above number that is not NA

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a table similar to this minimal example without the difference column:

| trigger | values | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |  |
| 0 | NA |  |
| 0 | NA |  |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 0 | 4 |  |
| 0 | NA |  |
| 1 | 10 | 6 |

I want to subtract the above number (and leave out the NAs) from the number at each trigger point (trigger = 1)

Is there a way to do this in R?

Edit:

I have now the situation where the triggers lie close together like in this example:

| trigger | values | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |  |
| 0 | NA |  |
| 0 | NA |  |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 0 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | 10 |  |

How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a grouping column with `cumsum` on the 'trigger' and taking the `lag`, then do the difference between the first and last element and `replace` it as the `last` value per group

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(trigger), default = 0)) %>% 
    mutate(difference = replace(rep(NA, n()), n(),
         values[n()] - values[1])) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  trigger values difference
    <int>  <int>      <int>
1       0      3         NA
2       0     NA         NA
3       0     NA         NA
4       1      5          2
5       0      4         NA
6       0     NA         NA
7       1     10          6
```

---

For the second case, we may need a condition with `if/else` that checks the number of rows i.e. `if` the number of rows is greater than 1 only need the computation to `replace`

```
df2 %>%  
  group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(trigger), default = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(difference = if(n() > 1) replace(rep(NA, n()), n(), 
         values[n()] - values[1]) else NA) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  trigger values   grp difference
    <int>  <int> <dbl>      <int>
1       0      3     0         NA
2       0     NA     0         NA
3       0     NA     0         NA
4       1      5     0          2
5       0      4     1         NA
6       1      5     1          1
7       0     10     2         NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(trigger = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), values = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

df2 <- structure(list(trigger = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), values = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I tested your code and get the error in select(-grp): unused argument (-grp). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ben probably you loaded another package having `select` function which masked the dplyr select.  Can you change it to `%>% dplyr::select(-grp)`

Comment: I have checked my dataset again and found that there is this situation where the triggers lie close together (see edit). How can I adjust your code to fix this problem?

Comment: I would leave it at your answer

Comment: @Ben I updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
# Import data: df => data.frame
df <- structure(list(trigger = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), values = c(3L, 
NA, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 10L), diff_col = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, -1L, NA, 
6L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

# Create an empty vector: diff_col => integer vector
df$diff_col <- NA_integer_

# Difference the X.values vector, ignoring NAs: 
# diff_col => integer vector
df[which(!(is.na(df$values)))[-1], "diff_col"] <- diff(
   na.omit(
      df$values
   )
)

# Nullify the value if the trigger is 0:
# diff_col => integer vector
df$diff_col <- with(
   df, 
   ifelse(
      trigger == 0,
      NA_integer_,
      diff_col
   )
)
```